# How to allocate properly aligned 2D texture?

Tags: cuda

I am doing linear interpolation on GPU. Straightforward hand-written code seems to work, but texture look-up using `tex2D` doesn't. I suspect that texture data maybe allocated incorrectly: [CUDA API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaDeviceProp.html#structcudaDeviceProp_1500248658a996f51752e1ab1769f8a88) refers to (rather cryptically) to `textureAlignment` and `texturePitchAlignment` that my call to `cudaMalloc` may be not honoring.

Could you suggest a preferred method of allocating texture on the device so that `tex2D` requirements would be fulfilled?

Comment: the [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#pitch-linear-texture) `simplePitchLinearTexture` gives a fully worked example of 2D texturing from a linear allocation.  The underlying allocation is not created with `cudaMalloc` but with `cudaMallocPitch`, and of course `cudaMemcpy2D` is used to populate the data.  Follow the path through that code associated with the `texRefPL` texture reference and the corresponding allocation associated with the pointer `d_idataPL`  (the call in question is not `text2D` but `tex2D`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11924537/681865